# Stop Screensaver using Task scheduler windows 8.1

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, screensaver, windows-tabletpc, nircmd

I have an old windows 8.1 tablet that I'm trying to set up as a digital picture frame.  It's a winbook tw700.

The tablet does not support wake timers so I have sleep for battery and plugged in as Never.

What I'm trying to do is stop the screensaver at a set time.
The script I'm using works fine if I manually open the .bin file but it isn't working with task scheduler.

I'm using nircmd
I have tried using sendkey and mouse, and cursor commands but none work.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks